# Saving multiple inline edits with CKEditor

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ckeditor, inline

I'm using asp.net and I would like to edit a newsletter using CKEditor’s inline editing capabilities and then save the newsletter to the database and send via an email.

I've seen various posts about getting the data from a single instance of the inline editor on a page.

Such as the answer by oleq to Dan Temple question on inline editing.
[How do I save inline editor contents on the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13922002/ckeditor-inline-edit)

However I would like to have a newsletter similar to the inline demo on the ckeditor site with multiple areas in different style that can be edited.
http://ckeditor.com/demo#inline

Then I guess using ajax to collate the data from each of the individual instances of the editor and save to the database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks. Luke

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does exactly what you are looking for:
[ckeditor inline save/submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603575/ckeditor-inline-save-submit)

You might need to change a few things to make it work for you. If you are writing valid HTML then I would suggest using something like Nokogiri to search and replace the contents of the page element id's instead of using regular expressions like this answer does.