# Save Data From Multiple CKEditor Inline Editor Fields Like A Template

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ckeditor

I'm setting up a template system where designers can submit HTML5 designs and allow users to add their own content. I'm using CKEditor 4.2 and Rails 3 for the app. I would like users to be able to load the template page and then edit the various inline editors directly, then save via JS and Ajax. I had everything working but when adding iFrame plugin I ran into some formatting issues because I was simply saving the raw HTML from the inline editors to my templates. See this question for more details: [CKEditor and iFrame/YouTube/Other Embed Plugins Show Weird HTML Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383748/ckeditor-and-iframe-youtube-other-embed-plugins-show-weird-html-code)

I now know I should use something like:

```
var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editable.getData();
```

But how would I manage multiple editors like this? I've told my designers to simply use

```
contenteditable="true"
```

for any div they want to be editable. Hence I have no id's to reference for each  editor and don't know how many editors each template file will contain I would like to be able to save both non-editable content and of course editable content in the final template, which is just a HTML5 page.

Here is the solution I had to save the raw contents of the entire template file using a div with id:

```
$saveButton.click(function(e) {

    // Extract contents of magboy container
    var contents = $("#page-cnt").html();

    // Send contents to server
    $.ajax({
        url: '/pages/'+PageId+'/editor_save',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            containerContents: contents
        },
        success: function(response){
            alert("contents saved");
        }
    });

    // prevent original click behaviour
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;

});
```

**So to sum up my question:**

How can I implement a save function that saves the content of several CKEditor editors in a complete template page?

Thanks so much for any help and if you can help with this question, then it will answer this same question also I believe: [Saving multiple inline edits with CKEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108461/saving-multiple-inline-edits-with-ckeditor)

Comment: You have done really good background work before posting this question, cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone looking to do something similar see this already answered question:
[ckeditor inline save/submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603575/ckeditor-inline-save-submit)