# Get div by id from string using PHP

Tags: php, regex, dom

I have a while dom document string inside variable, I want to grab only content of a div using id, I can't use PHP dom parser, is it possible using Regex?

```
<html>
....
<body>
....
<div id="something">
// content
</div>

<div id="other_divs">
// content
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Regex solution would be difficult, what is the reason why DOM parser is not an option?

Comment: Sounds like you should look into jQuery. What you are going to do with the content? http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-item-using-class-or-id/

Comment: It is possible, but only for certain cases. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) for more details.

Comment: Many clients will use this app, and some won't have dom parser installed by default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355452/using-a-regular-expression-to-match-a-div-block-having-a-specific-id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match('%<div[^>]+id="something"[^>]*>(.*?)</div>%si', $string)
```

If there is no additional div in the content itself.

Comment: almost certainly there would be div :)

Comment: yeah there is a lot of divs inside, but I can grab all sub divs each alone

Comment: Can you modify the html you're parsing?

Comment: Then it's not that easy. Is there an intendation for the content? If yes, you can do something like this: %<div[^>]+id="something"[^>]*>(.*?)^</div>%sim

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use this regexp, hope it will help  you.

```
preg_match_all('/<div\s*id="[^>]+">(.*?)<\/div>/s', $html, $match);  
print_r($match[0]);
```